# Django and javascript issue

Tags: javascript, django

I want to inject a variable into url like in the code. But It gives an error.

```
   function initializeDataTable(id){
        var columnSize = $('table th').size();
    $('#table').dataTable({
        "sDom" : 'rtFip>',
        'fnDrawCallback' : function() {
            $('input:checkbox, input:radio').checkbox();
        },
        "bStateSave": true,
        'sPaginationType' : 'full_numbers',
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "{% url 'get_menu_list' '" + id + "' %}"
   });
  };
```

I want to get the selected option and in the option change event, I will call the function above. How can I do that?

Comment: what error specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
"sAjaxSource" : "{% url 'get_menu_list' '" + id + "' %}"
```

`{% %}` are server-side directives. The server processes them and then puts them in the response page. The javascript function runs client-side. It can't talk to the server and ask it for data in the way you have expected it to do here. You will have to do something that doesn't depend on the server, such as:

```
"sAjaxSource": "/get_menu_list/" + id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up server side thing with client side.  This piece

```
 "{% url 'get_menu_list' '" + id + "' %}"
```

should be interpreted in server side. By then server side doesn't  know what is 'id' yet.

Comment: No it doesn't work.Mr Claudiu's solution works. I think we cannot use url reverse functions like that.

Comment: @Burak I was not saying it was working. I was explaining why the piece of code was wrong

Comment: Ah ok, I got what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Then you could pass url as a variable to your function:

```
<script>
function initializeDataTable(data_url) {
    var columnSize = $('table th').size();

    $('#table').dataTable({
        "sDom" : 'rtFip>',
        'fnDrawCallback' : function() {
            $('input:checkbox, input:radio').checkbox();
        },
        "bStateSave": true,
        'sPaginationType' : 'full_numbers',
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : data_url
   });
}

$(function(){
    initializeDataTable("{% url 'get_menu_list' item.id %}");
});
</script>
```

You could use tokens in your url:

```
<script>
var url_pattern = "{% url 'get_menu_list' '{id}' %}";
function initializeDataTable(id) {
    var columnSize = $('table th').size();

    $('#table').dataTable({
        "sDom" : 'rtFip>',
        'fnDrawCallback' : function() {
            $('input:checkbox, input:radio').checkbox();
        },
        "bStateSave": true,
        'sPaginationType' : 'full_numbers',
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : url_pattern.replace('{id}', id)
   });
}

$(function(){
    initializeDataTable(42);
});
</script>
```

Notice that your token should match the regex type to resolve successfully (you can't use `{id}` as token if it's defined with `\d+`, instead use `0000`).

I was a little bit unsatisfied with this solution and I ended by writing my own application to handle javascript with django: [django.js](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django.js).

With this application, you can do:

```
{% load js %}
{% django_js %}
<script>
function initializeDataTable(id) {
    var columnSize = $('table th').size();

    $('#table').dataTable({
        "sDom" : 'rtFip>',
        'fnDrawCallback' : function() {
            $('input:checkbox, input:radio').checkbox();
        },
        "bStateSave": true,
        'sPaginationType' : 'full_numbers',
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : Django.url('get_menu_list', id)
   });
}

$(function(){
    initializeDataTable(42);
});
</script>
```

To ensure that urls are loaded by Django.js, listen to the `ready` event:

```
// Wait for document ready
$(function(){
    initializeDataTable(42);
});

// Wait for Django ready
Django.onReady(function(){
    initializeDataTable(42);
});
```